# make right div rsponsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on dashboard in my project.I want to make right panel occupy rest of the space. Let me show you what it looks like right now.

[image: Collapse]

[image: expanded]

So in both scenario, I want to make right div responsive.

Now there is a cursor icon to toggle right panel named "menuToggle" (reproduced here as a simple button)

```js
$('#menuToggle').on('click', function (event) {
      debugger;
    $('body').toggleClass('open');
  });
```

```css
aside.left-panel {
 background: #272c33;
 display: table-cell;
        height: 100vh;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0 25px;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 280px;
        transition: width 0.3s ease;
    }
.right-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;
}
    .open aside.left-panel {
    max-width: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

aside.left-panel {
    background: #272c33;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 280px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.open .right-panel {
    margin-left: -210px;
}
.right-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="menuToggle">Menu Toggle</button>

<aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default">
    
                    
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
            </aside>
    <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
    <!-- Header-->
       <header id="header" class="header">
    
       </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding your question, do you want everything to cover the full width of the page?

Comment: yes sir @JimCiaston

Comment: Do you have a working link to your website?

Comment: No sir I am currently working in my local machine.. @GrandIQ

Comment: @GrandIQ Links to a website wouldn't be appropriate anyway, as all code to reproduce the issue must be present in the question (otherwise it is considered off-topic).

Comment: @Babai, I edited your question to make it a little easier to play with. If you don't like my edits, please feel free to rollback to the previous version: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51427570/revisions

Comment: No sir perfect :) @JDB , but  umm I also want the same effect while user will hover on left panel.

Comment: @JDB I know I already see his code but I feel like there are components that could effect it that are not listed.

Comment: It's your question, please feel free to edit it. That said, you deleted that line in revision 3, which is why it's missing.

Answer (score 3):

Here a flexbox example.

```js
$('#menuToggle').on('click', function (event) {
  // debugger;
  $('body').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

aside.left-panel {
  background: #272c33;
  /* display: table-cell; */
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 280px;
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

div.right-panel {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #EEE;
  /* display: table-cell; */
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.open aside.left-panel {
    /* max-width: 70px; */
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="menuToggle">Menu Toggle</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default">
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
    Some content...
    <!-- Header-->
    <header id="header" class="header">
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand you but it looks like you can adjust the padding in the `left-panel` to be `padding: 0px 10%` and then adjust the width in `right-panel` to be `width: 90%`.

I think it would make more sense if you removed the padding from `left-panel` and made it `width:10%`.